# Pool connection connects every time?

Tags: http, go, redis

I am trying to write a simple http server in go , accepting a query string and pushing that to redis.  I use the redigo module for redis connection and fasthttp for http server.

In the code (below). I am trying to use a redis pool, so that the connections are reused. When I try to benchmark using ab

```
ab -n 10000 -c 100 -k -r http://127.0.0.1:9080/?a=b
```

I see that almost 6000 redis connections are opened up. 
I can see that using netstat

Is the connection pooling not working ? How do I reduce the connections to redis ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"
    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
)

var Pool *redis.Pool
var err error

func init() {
    Pool = newPool("127.0.0.1:6379")
    _, err = Pool.Dial()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func newPool(server string) *redis.Pool {

    return &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle:     3,
        IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
        Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
            c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", server)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            return c, err
        },
    }
}

func fastHTTPHandler(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    conn := Pool.Get()
    defer conn.Close()
    conn.Do("RPUSH", "LTBENCH_PARAMS", ctx.QueryArgs().QueryString())

}

func main() {
    fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":9080", fastHTTPHandler)
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a realistic workload, and you might just be pulling pool connections faster than they are recycled. Try setting `MaxActive` and `Wait`

Comment: In addition to what previous comment says, `MaxIdle` may be low for this workload.  Some tuning of the pool settings is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're only allowing 3 idle connections in the pool at a time, so after the first concurrent batch of 100 clients is completed, up to 97 of those connections could be closed instead of re-used.

You need to set the `MaxIdle` to a value that can handle your expected concurrency, which is 100 in this case. If you want to put a limit on open connections, you should also set `MaxActive` and `Wait` so that spikes in activity don't exhaust server resources.

```
return &redis.Pool{
    MaxIdle:     100,
    IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
    MaxActive:   200,
    Wait:        true,
    Dial:        func() (redis.Conn, error) { return redis.Dial("tcp", addr) },
}
```

Comment: Yes that works. I had another doubt . Why do I need  statement "defer conn.Close()"  anyway the connection would close after the idle time . But if I remove that the performance drops

Comment: @Ram: the point of using a Pool is to reuse connections to get better performance. Not returning the connection to the pool means you're just wasting resources and Dialing new connections every time.

Comment: Right , so the performance should actually increase if I don't call conn.close() ... But that is reverse of what I see. If I call close I get 55k requests/s if I don't call close I get only 15k

Comment: @Ram, can you explain why you think doing a very slow operation thousands of times more than necessary would improve performance?